# Instantiating an Object using Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, junit

I am testing a `private` method using `JUnit` and I am invoking it using `Reflection`. The error I am getting is `java.lang.InstantiationException`. I know it is not creating an instance of `Class` but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. `Object object = clazz.newInstance();` is the line that throws `Exception`.

Method under test

```
 private int _getType(String type) {
    if ("DATE".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) return Types.DATE;
    if ("STRING".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) return Types.VARCHAR;
    if ("INT".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) return Types.INTEGER;
    if ("TIMESTAMP".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) return Types.TIMESTAMP;

    return Types.NULL;

}
```

JUnit test

```
@Test
public void testGetType() throws Exception {
    String type1 = "DATE";
    String type2 = "STRING";
    String type3 = "INT";
    String type4 = "TIMESTAMP";

    Class clazz = SpringStoredProcImpl.class;
    Object object = clazz.newInstance();

    Method method = object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getType", String.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);

    method.invoke(object, type1);
```

I don't have my asserts yet so please ignore it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You declare a method `_getType` and try to call `getType`. What's up with that?

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo. Still having the same issue.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Does this class actually have a zero-argument constructor for `clazz.newInstance()` to call?

Comment: This is what I was thinking. I got 2 overloaded constructors.

Comment: Constructors : `public SpringStoredProcImpl(DataSource dataSource,String sprocName, ArrayList params){}`, 

`public SpringStoredProcImpl(DataSource dataSource,String sprocName, ArrayList params, String rsName, RowMapper mapper)`

Comment: There is no need to invoke the contructor with reflection, since the class is not private (only the method), so better write `Object object = new SpringStoredProcImpl(dataSource, sprocName, params)` with arguments as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to create an instance with a `no argument constructor` which does exist in your case.

As the constructors are `public` you should first create your object normally using the `new` keyword, then execute the rest of your code starting from `Method method...`

FYI, if you wanted to create your object by reflection it would be something like `clazz.getConstructor(DataSource.class, String.class, ArrayList.class).newInstance(dataSource, sprocName, params)` instead of simply `clazz.newInstance()`

Answer (score 0):

Different answer: don't do that.

Why do you think you need to make this method private? It looks like the responsibility of this method is to "lookup" an enum type, based on string input. I think it would make much more sense to simply make this method package protected and avoid the reflection overhead/hassle.

Comment: You are correct but I cannot change the access modifier of the method or do anything with the model you know. But yeah it would make much more sense to make it package access extend the class and test it easily.